# how to cache useRequest response?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, axios

I am using `useRequest` from `ahooks` library. I specified `cacheKey` in options but the same request is repeated over and over when it is supposed to be retrieved from cache.

```
let someVar = 'someValue'
const { data, loading } = useRequest(
    async () => someRequestThatDependOnVariable(someVar),
    {
      refreshDeps: [someVar],
      cacheKey: `request-${someVar}`,
    },
  );
```

someVar is updated via select field

Comment: Can you please provide your code and example output so we can best assist you?

Answer (score 5):

> but the same request is repeated over and over when it is supposed to be retrieved from cache.

This is as designed.

According to [the documentation](https://ahooks.js.org/hooks/use-request/cache):

> If `options.cacheKey` is set, `useRequest` will cache the successful data . The next time the component is initialized, if there is cached data, we will return the cached data first, and then send a new request in background

So the point of `cacheKey` here is to hide the loading of data by showing previously cached data while the latest data is being fetched. This does not prevent the data from being loaded.

However, if you also use the `staleTime` property, you can tell it not to make a new query for some number of seconds from the last successful request.

> You can set the data retention time through `options.staleTime`. During this time, we consider the data to be fresh and will not re-initiate the request.

```
const { data, loading } = useRequest(
  async () => someRequestThatDependOnVariable(someVar),
  {
    refreshDeps: [someVar],
    cacheKey: `request-${someVar}`,
    staleTime: 10 * 60 * 1000 // 10 minutes in milliseconds
  },
);
```

Comment: i set network to slow 3g but my data is not shown, and loading is true until request is done

Comment: i guess staleTime will work for me if it works

Comment: actually this does not work, request is repeated even with staleTime set